# Json data type parsing to Typescript Interface data types

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I convert data types to number using JSON.parse and Reviver function? Have tried some options and examples but not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Background is that I'm using Typescript interface which has defined types but incoming Json file has "" for all values.

I only need to apply transformation from String to Number, no other cases exist.

JSON input example ->

```
{"sub_type": "0", "year": "2023", "peak": "N"}
```

Expected output

```
{"sub_type": 0, "year": 2023, "peak": "N"}
```

I have tried following snippet to make it happen:

```
    let cards: Array<Card> = pt_cards['data'];
    let tstCard: Card = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cards[0]), (key, value) => {
        if(!isNaN(value)) {
            return(key: value);
        }
        return value;
    });
```

Or should I just replace current Interface  declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Try so:

```js
JSON.parse(jsonString, (key, value) => {

   if (!isNaN(value)) {
      return Number(value);
   }

   return value;
});
```

Only if the value represents a number then is converted to a number

Comment: Simple and elegant, and does the trick quite well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to `JSON.stringify` just to `JSON.parse` it again. Verify this example on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMD6DGBDATgEygXigbwFBSgGcBXAI1lEgC4oA7YgW1ImXyhAhRvqZbckQBrGoWDIAlrQDmuAL65claHEItxiADbiAXhFQIU6LHgIlySkWMkyCHLkSvT+nYQ4lP5uAGbFa8YOIA9rRu1gAqgQByjMzIAKIAHrQAFISW7lIAlNwxLDhs8MGidJhQ0bzIAHRgKKoAkrTAqZls4l5QyeWxleKEkYiRybSZLQQEwAAWyIEA7lBxyNPIyQAGohkRXSyJtDQAJNiEslC9dIHAUIh0ucgro1DIEMDEyCG0cgqIhCB+UD5+AWCUCkTwAwoZCMlslAAArTBi9CAAHgAgotECAkXAkGgAHy4-IEAD0RL+gWQDEQFy+DyeL1oej+8KgpEQ8EEEFoqAKRQujzSUDRyAxWNgqgkmh0egMeNKbAIiBmiHEFy8T3gE2SACIiTVJkTgIEiTjUIQtZlKpNOclkJgCVUAFaEYJQlpsElQSlgGCBKCoCCEcSPdBecmUi5sR7PV60wiVL3JE12jomMZmCjgCDpcJRG47ROGSrppSZAA08vYnGQ2ekmzzSQLaEqdmQZYrAlcJuqLjYshGHyAA) -

```
type t_card = {
  sub_type: number
  year: number
  peak: string
}

type t_serialized_card = {
  sub_type: string
  year: string
  peak: string
}

function stringToNumberExn(s: string): number {
  const n = Number.parseInt(s)
  if (Number.isNaN(n))
    throw Error(`stringToNumberExn: ${s} is not a number`)
  return n
}

async function getCards(): Promise<Array<t_card>> {
  // format as returned from backend
  const res: Array<t_serialized_card> = 
    await fetch("/path/to/cards").then(r => r.json())

  // map to desired format 
  return res.map(card => ({
    sub_type: stringToNumberExn(card.sub_type),
    year: stringToNumberExn(card.year),
    peak: card.peak
  }))
}
```